# Volume of an Ellipsoid by double integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I was finding the volume of the ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$ and the answer is supposed to be $\frac{4}{3}\pi abc$, but I am repeatedly getting $\frac{4}{3}\pi ac$. I am writing below the steps I followed:

$V=\int^a_{-a}\int^{\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}_{\frac{-b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}2c\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}} dy\space dx$

$V=8c\int^a_0\int^{\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}_0\sqrt{(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a})^2-(\frac{y}{b})^2} dy\space dx$

Using $\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx = \frac{x}{2}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\arcsin(x/a)+C$,
we have

$\int\sqrt{(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a})^2-(\frac{y}{2})^2} dy = \frac{y}{2b}\sqrt{\frac{a^2-x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}+\frac{a^2-x^2}{2a^2}\arcsin(\frac{ya}{b\sqrt{a^2-x^2}})+C$

Therefore,

$\int^{\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}_0\sqrt{(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a})^2-(\frac{y}{b})^2} dy = \frac{a^2-x^2}{2a^2}\frac{\pi}{2}\space$  (since rest of the terms become zero)

Hence,

$V=2\pi c\int^a_0(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})dx$
$V=2\pi c (a-\frac{a^3}{3a^2})$

$V=\frac{4}{3}\pi ac$

I know I must have eaten something somewhere, but I am not able to find where. Please help me figure out where I made mistake.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would say $V=\int^a_{-a}\int^{\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}_{\frac{-b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} 2c \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\color{red}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}} dy\space dx$, but a better approach would be different.

Comment: Yes, thats how I found the integral.. but I made mistake somewhere and am unable to find it

Comment: I would say, the mistake be the sign under the root (red color). I thought not about it.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the function to negative sign... but note that in spite of that positive sign I used the right formula for integration and then I am again getting incorrect result... maybe there is some other mistake too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integral 
$$ \int_0^A\sqrt{A^2-x^2}\mathrm dx={A^2}\frac\pi4$$
the change of variable $x=y/b$ brings
$$ \int_0^{bA}\sqrt{A^2-\left(\frac yb\right)^2}\mathrm dy={A^2b} \frac\pi4$$
Thus your mistake is here
$$\int^{\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}_0\sqrt{\frac{a^2-x^2}{a^2}-\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2} \mathrm dy =\color{red}b \frac{a^2-x^2}{a^2} \frac\pi4 $$

Comment: @Ritu. You have two perfectly acceptable answers, at different levels. Jack's answer is more profound than my technical answer. You should now accept either, by clicking the check sign.

Answer (score 5):

Too much work for something really trivial. An affine map sends the ellipsoid into the unit sphere, whose volume is well-known ($\frac{4\pi}{3}$). Hence you just have to compute the determinant of a diagonal Jacobian matrix ($abc$). Profit.

Comment: My assignment demands me to use this method only. Can you help me find the mistake? The 'b' somehow got vanished..